# How to make multi-row cell in SWT Table under MacOS

Tags: java, macos, swt, jface

I have a cross-platform SWT/Jface application with tables. Some table cells may content muli-line values separated by \n symbol. They display normally under Linux: they are expanded along the column increasing the cell height. But in MacOS they are collapsed and I can see the full contents of a cell only when I hover the mouse over it. See my gif screencast.

How to configure a table so that it displays the entire contents of a cell under MacOS?

```
    tableViewer2 = new TableViewer(group, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    tableViewer2.setLabelProvider(getLabelProvider());
    Table table = tableViewer2.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    if (null == data2)
        table.removeAll();
    else {
        tableViewer2.setInput(data2);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
            table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }
```

[image: collapsed multi-row table cells in MacOS]

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. It is possible to increase the row height for all rows using the `SWT.MeasureItem` event, but that is a fixed height and applies to all rows. Anything more complicated would require something like [nattable](https://eclipse.dev/nattable/)

Comment: @greg-449 the fact is that in Linux, table row resizes automatically in accordance with the contents of a biggest cell. But MacOS hides the cell's content, showing only its first line. It seems that this is a feature of Apple operating system. So I thought, maybe there is some kind of table setting (or redrawing method) in SWT that allows to automatically adjust the cell size after filling the table?

Comment: I don't think the macOS `NSTableView` that SWT uses supports doing this automatically. So as far as I know the SWT.MeasureItem listener is the only way change the row height (for all rows).

Comment: As a basis I took the listener described here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/MultilineTablecell.htm